# How do I prevent re-sizing the browser window from moving elements beneath each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with CSS.

Say I have two image elements adjacent to each other. How do I make it so, if I change the size of the browser to be smaller than the width of the two images, it'll cause the page to get a horizontal scroll bar (as opposed to pushing the second image beneath the first)?

Comment: Put them in a container div with a defined width equal or greater to the sum of the images.

Comment: There's a million ways to do something.  Where is your specific code example?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use relative positioning

example:

```
test
{
position:relative;
left:200px;
}
```

This way the position of your image will be based on the position of the other objects to it's left (in your case another image).

You can also put an absolute position, based on the windows coordinates.

hope this helps
IronWill